# How to trace my jersey client call

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

With latest Jersey, (2.23?), I'd like to use a transaction like api to trace my jersey call.

for example:

client.target("/abc").request(MediaType.TEXT_HTML_TYPE).get(String.class);

My transaction should begin when "get" gets invoked.
and should end when I got the response. (before read entity)

That's to say, my transaction should include calls of:

- ClientRequestFilters
- WriterInterceptors
- MessageBodyWriter
- wait response from server
- ClientResponseFilters

My questions:

1. Where to plugin my transaction begin/end logic?
2. If any of above stages has exeception thrown, I need to catch it for sure to close my transaction and throw it again. Is it doable?

Thanks

Leon

Comment: This question seems a bit abstract for me. Maybe adding some code will clarify it and will maximize your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: By transaction like api, it looks like:

transaction.start();

doSomethingThatCostTime();

transaction.end();

with this way, I can measure the cost of the overall jersey call.

1 option is to place transaction.start at the first ClientRequestFilter and put transaction.end at the last ClientResponseFilter.

But I doubt this is a good choice, especially when exceptions could be throw in any phase in between.